# How to use the useContext() hook inside a component which is wrapped within an HOC?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have a Login component and an App component. The App component contains the Login component within a context Provider. The Login component is in turn wrapped by the withFormik higher-order component for form validation. When I try to use the useContext() hook in the Login component, it fails to compile with the error:

***./src/components/login/Login.jsx***

***Line 12:  React Hook "useContext" is called in function "login" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks***

Tried going through the React docs as well, but couldn't fix this. :(

Login.jsx:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { withFormik, Form, Field } from 'formik';

import { RenderInput, RenderMobileNumberInput } from '../../utils/input.util';
import { isMobile, isPassword } from '../../utils/validation.util';

import AuthContext from '../../store/auth.store';

import '../../styles/login.scss';

const login = props => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  console.log('authContext', authContext);

  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <div className="login-content">
        <h1 className="header">Agent Login</h1>
        <div className="login-form">
          <Form>
            <div className="input-row">
              <label htmlFor="mobile">Mobile Number</label>
              <Field
                component={RenderMobileNumberInput}
                countrycode="+91"
                name="mobile"
                placeholder="Mobile Number"
                validate={isMobile}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="input-row">
              <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
              <Field
                type="password"
                component={RenderInput}
                name="password"
                placeholder="Enter Password"
                validate={isPassword}
              />
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-yellow" type="submit">
              Login
            </button>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const FormikApp = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues(props) {
    return {
      mobile: props.mobile || '',
      password: props.password || '',
    };
  },
  handleSubmit(values) {
    console.log(values);
  },
})(login);

export default FormikApp;
```

App.jsx:

```
// Importing required NPM modules
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

// Importing local modules & components
import Login from './components/login/Login';

import AuthContext from './store/auth.store';

// Impoting stylesheets
import './App.scss';

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={‌{ isAuthenticated: false }}>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

auth.store.js:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

const initialContext = {
  user: null,
  isAuthenticated: false,
};

const authContext = createContext({ ...initialContext });

export default authContext;
```

index.js:

```
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-filename-extension */
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import './index.scss';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

// Importing store contexts
import AuthContext from './store/auth.store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{}}>
      <App />
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says exactly what it needs / wants to say. Hook can only be called inside a React functional component. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

While you write your `login` component as a functional component, wrap it with the `withForm` HOC turn it to a class component. You should read the `withFormik` source code to see it: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/next/src/withFormik.tsx.

Basically, what `withFormik` HOC does (and many other HOCs do the same thing), is to wrap your component inside a class component. It is done this way so additional props (usually referred to as `injected props`) can be passed to your component.

To solve your problem, you should avoid using react hooks with `withFormik` HOC. You can choose to use `Formik` component instead of the `withFormik` HOC.

Comment: I tried eliminating the use of withFormik HOC totally. Just made a functional component which return just a single blank <div>. It still throws the same error.

Comment: Fixed it. The problem was not with the withFormik HOC, but with a React hooks update, which enforces the use of Capital notation for component names, even for functional components. After replacing the component name 'login' with 'Login', it is working just fine, with the withFormik HOC too.